# MutliSelect ListBox in Menu

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I am creating an undo button that should work identical to visual studios undo button. I want the user to be able to mouse over an item and every item above it is selected. On click all items above are passed in and actions performed. If the user clicks the button itself, undo the top object. Problem: not using a context menu and no idea what I'm doing with wpf. Right now the user can mouse over but only the object that the mouse is above is selected (all code behind is vb.net). All help is appreciated!

Code:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Undo" Name="MenuUndo" IsEnabled="True">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="Undo.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxUndo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch " 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="177" Height="100 " Margin="-33,-5,-65,-5" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True"
                SelectionMode ="Multiple">

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListBox>                       
    </StackPanel>

</MenuItem>
```

here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work by using the scroll wheel which works kind of better anyways! Here is the code that i added:

```
 Private Sub ListBoxUndo_PreviewMouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseWheelEventArgs) Handles ListBoxUndo.PreviewMouseWheel
    ListBoxUndo.Focus()
    Try
        If e.Delta < 1 Then
            'highlight next item
            ListBoxUndo.SelectedItems.Add(ListBoxUndo.Items(ListBoxUndo.SelectedItems.Count))

        Else
            'remove last selected item
            ListBoxUndo.SelectedItems.Remove(ListBoxUndo.Items(ListBoxUndo.SelectedItems.Count - 1))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```